# Setting Android Theme Color for Wordpress Page

Tags: web-applications, wordpress-theming, meta-tags, chrome-for-android

I'm building a wordpress theme and want to use the theme-color meta tag to set the toolbar color for the website when viewed in chrome for Android. No matter what I set the theme color to, it always comes out black. For example:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#CFCFCF">
```

Not the most important design element of my site, but I'd love to be able to use it if possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was adding this to one of my sites today and came across exactly the same problem. It turned out I was missing the # symbol in front of the hex value. As soon as I added it, the color changed to the one I had specified. I see the # in your posted code, but double check it again both in your code and in your live page source.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Mine did have it. But when I get a chance I will go back and double check my syntax.